# highlight the queried text in the recycleView list ignoring space

Tags: android, searchview, spannablestring

I am trying to highlight the queried text in the recycleView list.
My requirement is to ignore space and highlight the text.

**My List**: ["Robert De Niro", "Jack Nicholson", "Marlon Brando"]

**Search query** : DeNiro

**Expected**: Robert **De N**iro

Below is my code

```
  private Spannable getHighlightedText(String wholeText, String searchText) {

    if (searchText != null && wholeText.toLowerCase().contains(searchText.toLowerCase())) {
        int startPos = wholeText.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase());
        int endPos = startPos + searchText.length();

        Spannable spanString = Spannable.Factory.getInstance().newSpannable(wholeText);
        spanString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.primary)), startPos, endPos, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        return spanString;
    }

    return new SpannableString(wholeText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove space from your search string before your check

```
searchText= searchText.trim().replace(" ", "");
```

your function will be like this

```
private Spannable getHighlightedText(String wholeText, String searchText) {


  String searchTextWithOutSpace=searchText.trim().replace(" ", "");


  if (searchText != null && ( wholeText.toLowerCase().contains(searchTextWithOutSpace.toLowerCase()) ||
      //add another condition because mybae user write searchText with space  
      wholeText.toLowerCase().contains(searchText.toLowerCase())) ) {
    int startPos = wholeText.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase());
    int endPos = startPos + searchText.length();

    Spannable spanString = Spannable.Factory.getInstance().newSpannable(wholeText);
    spanString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.primary)), startPos, endPos, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    return spanString;
  }

  return new SpannableString(wholeText);
}
```

Comment: If i do then    **searchText= searchText.trim().replace(" ", "");** then .   **int startPos = wholeText.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase());**  will retuen -1

Comment: Thanks for helping.
I will explain it with an example. 
**wholeText** = "Mahmoud Abu Elheja"
**searchText** = "AbuE"

So by your logic, we are making lowercase and delete space
**searchTextWithOutSpace** = "abue"

Below line will return -1

**wholeText.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase());**
"mahmoud bbu elheja".indexOf("abue")

Comment: @Ananth No i used (searchText) not (searchTextWithOutSpace)  when use indexOf so : "mahmoud abu elheja".indexOf("abu e")